# decomposition of matrix of matrices

Tags: matrices, tensors, matrix-decomposition, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Suppose I have a matrix $A$ where each entry is also a matrix, i.e., $A_{ij}\in R^{n\times n}$. Let us suppose every $A_{ij}$ is positive semi-definite as well. Question is: Do there exists $\{B_i\},\{C_j\}$ such that $A_{ij}=B_i C_j$ for every $i,j\in [n]$? Any reference also is welcome.

A version of this is true if we just had a positive semidefinite matrix, then every entry can be written as $A_{ij}=\langle x_i,x_j\rangle$.

Comment: Note: this amounts to the decomposition
$$
A = \pmatrix{B_1\\ \vdots \\ B_p} \pmatrix{C_1 & \cdots & C_q}
$$
In fact, this is just a *rank* decomposition, and this can be done if and only if $A$ has rank at most $n$.

Comment: *rank factorization* is actually the more common term

Comment: Also: if the overall matrix $A$ is positive semidefinite, then I believe that there exists such a factorization in which $C_i = B_i^T$.

Comment: are you doing a factorization every matrix $A_{ij}$ or on $A$ as a whole when viewed as a $n^2\times n^2$ matrix? Let us assume for now that $A$ as a whole and $A_{ij}$ have full rank

Comment: $A$ as a whole.  If $A$ as a whole has full rank, then no such factorization exists.